# Check if a list item exist in a dictionary

Tags: python, python-2.7

How can I check if a list exist in a dictionary whose item is a list? For example, I have the following dictionary:

```
dict1 = {0:[0,1,3], 1:[0,2,3]}
```

For example, `[1,0,3]` exist in `dict1` and return the corresponding `key`, but `[2,3]` does not exist in `dict1`.

Comment: You could solve this in a loop or generator expression converting each value to a sorted list and comparing... but is that really what you want?

Comment: @KlausD. yes `[1,0,3]` exists in the `dict1` as `[0,1,3]`. the item in the list can appear in any order.

Comment: [0, 1, 3] is not the same as [1, 0, 3]. If the order of the list items doesn't matter, than you are searching for 'a list with exactly all the items in your list'.

Comment: @VivekPabani. Yes I know `[0,1,3]` and `[1,0,3]` are not the same. In my case order deosn't matter.

Comment: Then it might be better to work with sets instead of lists.

Comment: @KlausD.Yes I am ok to use sets. But is it possible to have one-liner to search for a list in `dict1`.

Answer (score 2):

Taking advantage of the fact that one list (not list of lists) will be matched only to one value of dictionary, you could make use of a generator expression with a default `None`:

```
>>> dict1 = {0:[0, 1, 3], 1:[0, 2, 3]}
>>> lst = [1, 0, 3]
>>> next((k for k, v in dict1.items() if sorted(v) == sorted(lst)), None)
0
```

Answer (score -1):

A one liner to search for a **value**, not a **key** in a dictionary is:

```
any(x == <some-value> for x in dict1.itervalues())
```

But note this is a **linear** search.  If order does not matter, and items cannot be duplicated and are hashable, then ideally you would be storing your values as sets:

```
>>> dict1 = {0: set([0, 1, 3]), 1: set([0,2,3])}
```

Then you can search as simply:

```
>>> any(x == set([1, 0, 3]) for x in dict1.itervalues())
True
```

If you do not wish to store them as sets, and your lists might contain duplicates or unhashable objects then you could compare sorted values.  To make it more efficient in that case, you should presort your search value:

```
>>> dict1 = {0: [0, 1, 3]), 1: [0,2,3]}
>>> search_value = sorted([1, 0, 3])
>>> any(sorted(x) == search_value for x in dict1.itervalues())
True
```